# How to show the highest or the lowest value stored in a register bank in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

So, I'm trying to make a code that shows the highest or the lowest value stored in a register bank (we will store some values before we try to show anything). My ideia is to use a counter that goes through the address of the register bank and somehow use a comparator and  registers to compare and store the intermediate values, but  all my attempts are failing. Any suggestion?

This is my register bank, the output of the counter would connect to `read_adress`
but I'm not sure how I should control the `read_data` to show the highest or the lowest value.

```
 library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity b_reg is
     Generic(m : integer := 4; 
                 n: integer := 2 
      );
    Port ( 

            CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
            clear  : in STD_LOGIC;

            write_data : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(m-1 downto 0);
         write_adress  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0); 
         e_wr : in STD_LOGIC; -- enable writting

        read_adress :in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0); -- reading adress
            read_data : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(m-1 downto 0)  -- output

            );


end b_reg;

architecture Behavioral of b_reg is
    type r_array is array (0 to (2**n)-1) of std_logic_vector(m-1 downto 0);
    Signal memoria: r_array;
begin

process(clear,CLK,e_wr) is 
 begin
        if clear='1' then   
            for  i  in  0 to 2**n-1  loop
                memoria(i) <= (OTHERS => '0');  
            end loop;
            elsif RISING_EDGE(CLK) then
                    if e_wr ='1' then
                        memoria(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(write_adress ))) <= write_data; -- writting
                    end if;
        end if;
    end process escrever;

process(CLK,memoria,read_adress) is
    begin 
        read_data <= memoria(TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(read_adress)));  -- reading
    end process ler;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You have the right basic idea, the rest is detail. Go through one of your attempts in detail, in simulation. Find out why it is failing, fix that, until you get the desired result. You haven't told us any more about them so until you do, that's about all I can suggest.

Comment: Your code doesn't analyze, having end labels (escrever, ler) on two process statements without labels which is an error. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 process statement, para 9 "If a label appears at the end of a process statement, the label shall repeat the process label." Show us the attempt or your choce and demonstrate the error you got from it. Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, in the first process `e_wr` and in the second process `CLK` is not required in the sensitivity list.